# left-over grub/ubuntu after partition removal in windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I am new to ubuntu. I tried installing 14.04 as dual boot with windows 10 on dell xps 13. It wasn't completely working, so I decided to install instead 15.10. I removed the ubuntu partition from inside windows 10. I made a bootable usb with 15.10 and then tried reinstalling. Couple of issues.

1. On rebooting, the usb is not visible.
2. The secure boot option is enabled in UEFI.
3. ubuntu is still there in the bootup screen.
4. When I power down and start, grub comes up.

What do I need to do to clean out the precious ubuntu and reinstall?

Edit to answer the question: In the BIOS Setup, boot from USB had to be added. This is done by restarting the machine with the USB installed, pressing F12 (at least on the Dell I have) to get into the boot menu, and then going into the BIOS Setup  to add the boot from USB as an option

Comment: I meant previous!

Comment: Some UEFI require you to enable boot of any other device. Especially if Secure boot is on, as booting a flash drive may not be secure. Check options in UEFI. With Secure boot off or if external enabled, you should have the option to boot Ubuntu flash drive. If secure boot is off you get two boot options, one UEFI like UEFI: flash drive and the other just flash drive which is for BIOS boot. If UEFI booting in live mode you get the flash drive's grub menu. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: I disabled secure boot. The ubuntu flash drive is still not visible. This must be something else. Thanks.

Comment: I looked at the other similar questions, but it doesn't look like it others have had this issue. Could it be 'fast boot' related?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) – Re-installing Ubuntu is not much different from the first installation.

Comment: It always then is check ISO is correct & that install of ISO is correct to flash drive. Some also have issues with certain combinations of installer and/or brands of flash drives. What installer? Many have success from Windows with Rufus or Win32 Disk Imager. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb OR: http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media

Comment: The most common cause of an inability to boot a USB flash drive with an Ubuntu installer on it is that the USB flash drive was prepared incorrectly. There are numerous tools to do this job -- [Rufus,](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) [Unetbootin,](http://unetbootin.github.io/) `dd`, and more. Some of these tools have multiple options or work differently depending on how the USB drive was prepared *before* being fed to the program. Worse, what works for one computer may fail with another. Thus, you may need to try two or three ways of preparing your USB drive before you find one that will work *for you.*

Comment: After burning another USB with the ISO and failing, eventually it turned out, after a bit of experimenting, that I had to add USB as a boot option in BIOS Setup. So that was not an automatic thing. The question is why  the USB was in the menu at the first install but not thereafter. I certainly appreciate everyone's suggestions and tried at least a few of hose. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the BIOS Setup, boot from USB had to be added. This is done by restarting the machine with the USB installed, pressing F12 (at least on the Dell I have) to get into the boot menu, and then going into the BIOS Setup to add the boot from USB as an option